# only calls to certain template class member functions work

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template container class and I need to call some functions.
The below display function works fine, but then I call another functions and I get errors. The one with errors has parameters and the other doesn't, not sure if this is the reason. Maybe I am calling it wrong and I am missing some template syntax.

One function just displays the int and one "compares" the ints.

```
int main()
{
        Codeword<vector<int> >codeWord(intList); 
        Codeword<vector<int> >codeWord2(intList2);

        codeWord.displayWord();
        codeWord2.displayWord();
        codeWord.distance(codeWord2);//line 80 from error
}
```

Template class:

```
template<class T>
class Codeword
{
    private:
    T containerName;

    public:
    Codeword(T _containerName) : containerName(_containerName) {};

    void distance(Codeword obj);
    void displayWord();
};
```

This works:

```
 template<class T>
    void Codeword<T>::displayWord()
    {
        int genWeight = weight();
        for(int i = 0; i < containerName.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << containerName[i].getNumber() << " ";
        }
        cout << "   ";
        cout << "Weight: " << genWeight << endl;
    }
```

This doesnt:

```
template<class T>
void Codeword<T>::distance(T codeWordTwo)
{
    int difference = 0;

    for(int i =0; i < containerName.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << "Num1: " << containerName[j].getNumber() << " Num 2: " << codeWordTwo[j].getNumber() << endl;
            difference += containerName[j].getNumber() - codeWordTwo[j].getNumber();
            cout << "Diff: " << difference << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
"driver.cpp", line 80: Error: Formal argument obj of type std::vector<int> in call to Codeword<std::vector<int>>::distance(std::vector<int>) is being passed Codeword<std::vector<int>>.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message.

Comment: edited the post, to show error and line number

Comment: Off-topic: As is, `distance` accepts a T *by value*. As using `std::vector<int>`, you'll create a *copy* of the entire vector. Distance doesn't modify the vector, so accepting by const reference (sparing the copy) is much more efficient. Same applies for the entire `Codeword` as soon as adjusting according to @Yunnosch 's answer.

Comment: `T containerName;` <-> `containerName[j].getNumber()` <-> `Codeword<std::vector<int>>` – that won't work, `int` doesn't have a `getNumber` member...

Comment: so for example instead of the codeword having ints in it, it has a class "Mint" objects that is not a template, how could i call getNumber() then? is it something similiar to maybe  codeWord2.template getNumber<T>()? regular calls do not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create this way in main

```
Codeword<vector<int> >codeWord(intList);
```

then `T` is `vector<int>`.
Hence here, `T` still is:

```
template<class T>
void Codeword<T>::distance(T codeWordTwo)
```

I.e. the function requires a `vector<int>`, not a `Codeword`.

That is what the compiler tells you.

If you want to do this, i.e. to give a Codeword:

```
codeWord.distance(codeWord2);
```

Then you should declare the function accordingly:

```
template<class T>
void Codeword<T>::distance(Codeword<T> codeWordTwo)
```

Comment: Hm, I don't think question author is aware that she/he's having copies of the code words, maybe recommend, too, rather using const references instead?

Comment: @Aconcagua Let me see what the consequence of that is ... What could go wrong because of that in your opinion? ... Since distance only reads and does not attempt to modify the parameter, I only see a performance issue. Do I miss something?

Comment: Hm, I might have (as mre lacking)... `getNumber` might not be `const`, so we might need to hint to, too.

Comment: I did not see those gaps in the MRE I admit. Interesting way of expecting a special int vector... I think however that the immediate problem in this question can be solved with the non-MRE as it is. Lets see the ensuing questions and trust that this does not turn into a moving target. However, my respect for your thoroughness and eye for consequences. @Aconcagua